# Adding an ID KEY when Exporting SQL Server Query Results to CSV file

Tags: sql-server, csv, export

I need to export my query results from SQL Server 2008 to a CSV file and I wanted to know what is the easiest/best way to add a ID KEY (basicly a row number field) to my CSV file. Should I do this in the query? If so what would be the best code to do this? Or is there a way to add this type of "row number" field when exporting as CSV from SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easyest way is to use Excel or other spreedsheet editor to generate this numbers for you.
Just type in the first and second number and doubleclick on the black square at the bottom right corner of the seconde cell and you're good to go.

To make it with SQL you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY some fields asc, ...)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: I would have to do it in SQL because the query returns over a million records which i then need to import into access. When I import into access I'm getting a few extra records (appear to be duplicates) so I want to add the row numbers in excel so I can try to find the field that is causing the duplicate records. (i think it's some special character in one of the fields in the CSV file that is causing the extra records)